# Prevent Slurm user from running scancel on his/her own job

Tags: bash, slurm, hpc

In our HPC setup where Slurm is installed, after a user logs in using ssh, a script is executed where a job is submitted using srun with an interactive bash. The script is placed on .profile and the user cannot modify it. This is the contents of the bash script file.

> srun -A <ACCOUNT_NAME> -p  --mem=< MEMORY> --time=HH:MM:SS -N <NUM_NODES> --gres=gpu:<NUM_GPU>  --pty /bin/bash -i

Is there a way to prevent this user from bypassing slurm? Since the user can perform scancel on the job id anyway. Or is there a way to prevent the user from performing the scancel command?

Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way to prevent users from managing their own job (you could create wrappers that submit/manage jobs with another user id, but that would be difficult to manage/maintain/).

One option could be to add `exit` or `logout` after the `srun ...` line in `.profile` so that as soon as the Slurm job is terminated (either `scancel`led or after the user has `exit`ed from the interactive session, the SSH session is terminated as well.

```
srun -A ...
exit
```

Another option is to `exec` the `srun` command rather than simply running it:

```
exec srun -A ...
```

so that the `srun` instance replaces the Bash instance running outside of the control of Slurm. As soon as `srun` is terminated (for either reason as above), the user will be disconnected.

Comment: I tried both of these suggestions but it did not work. I tested adding 'exit' and 'logout' after the srun. When I canceled the job using the scancel command, it only exited into the bash screen and the ssh session was still active. I also tried using the 'exec srun -A...' and it also did not work. I also tested changing the time limit of srun (10 seconds) just to check if the exit and logout will be run after job completion. However, it also did not work.

Comment: Both solutions worked for me. Make sure the `.profile` script is sourced and not executed.

Comment: It now worked, thank you!. I followed your suggestion. I think this is also similar to what is stated here re sourcing the script: https://serverfault.com/questions/261802/what-are-the-functional-differences-between-profile-bash-profile-and-bashrc.